Seeking Tools for Efficient Illustration Design in Physics Book Project
One of my friends intends to write a book related to the field of physics. I have been assigned to design illustrations similar to the images below for his book. The total number of these illustrations is about 150. I am familiar with tools like PowerPoint, Illustrator, and Photoshop. However, given the volume of work, I am looking for recommendations on tools that publishers use to increase efficiency and save time. If you know of any suitable tools for my work or have any experience in this area, please guide me...




TikZ is as close to an industry standard as there is.

Thank you, my friend.
